# Flutter: How to use CupertinoSliverRefreshControl with SliverAppBar when stretch = true

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a Flutter UI that has an expandable app bar when the user over scrolls from the top but *also* implements pull-to-refresh functionality when the user over scrolls. I can easily implement one feature at a time but when I try to do both at once, only the app bar is stretched. The Cupertino refresh indicator will not appear no matter how far I pull down within the scroll view.

For various reasons, I want the refresh indicator to appear below the app bar and before the other slivers. I am trying to avoid using other pull to refresh indicator implementations that display over the app bar.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve something like this in Flutter?

I cannot embed images yet so here is a link to an animated gif showing the nature of the behavior I am looking for. Instead of a green sliver, I am of course wanting to display a refresh indicator.
[Simulated UI animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZznu.gif)

Below is simplified code that demonstrates the current behavior. If you comment out the stretch property of SliverAppBar or set it to false, the refresh indicator of CupertinoSliverRefreshControl will appear when expected. Ideally I'd get the stretchy app bar plus the Cupertino refresh indicator right below it when I over scroll. In effect, I want the two components to share the over scroll. E.g. When I over scroll by 100 pixels, I want the app bar to stretch by 50 pixels and the refresh indicator to expand by 50 pixels. Even better, I want to be able to more finely control the distribution ratio. e.g. 100 pixel over scroll = 30 pixel app bar stretch + 70 pixel refresh indicator.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            stretch: true, //<-- comment out this line (or set to false) to make CupertinoSliverRefreshControl work
            expandedHeight: 100,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                'Home',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
            onRefresh: () async {},
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE August 1, 2023**
I was able to create a piece of sample code that simulates the type of behavior I am looking for. In the below code, the green container will only appear during over scroll and will expand up to 100 pixels. Both the SliverAppBar and the green container can expand at the same time during the over scroll. This sample at least proves that this type of behavior is possible. Unless someone provides an alternative approach, I will likely write a custom version of CupertinoSliverRefreshControl based on the below sample code. I'm hoping y'all can help me save some time, though.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 100,
            pinned: true,
            stretch: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                'Home',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: min(
                  100.0,
                  min(
                          0,
                          scrollController.hasClients
                              ? scrollController.offset
                              : 0)
                      .abs()
                      .toDouble()),
              child: const Text('I will only appear during overscroll'),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              child: const Text('I am visible all the time'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use Stack[] widget to get that

Comment: Thanks @TasnuvaTavasumoshin . Can you please elaborate or point me to some page somewhere that you think could help me use a Stack to implement this UI?